# Translate SQL into knex

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, knex.js

I am Using knex and objection to make an API. I am trying to translate the SQL below into knex without using raw so I can get all posts associated with a list of groups and other users. The data is spread across 4 tables groups, posts, votes, and friends.

```
select posts.*, sum(voted.vote), users.full_name
        from  users, posts left outer join voted
        on posts.id = voted.post_id
        where(users.id = posts.user_id and posts.group_id = ${group_id})
        group by posts.id, voted.post_id, users.full_name;`);
console.log(post.rows[0], 'post from rows
```

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

You're fine: nothing about this SQL is out of the ordinary, and all can be represented using the Knex API. However, it makes sense to express the implicit join:

```
FROM users, posts
```

as an explicit join:

```
FROM users
JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.user_id
```

meaning that you can drop the first part of your `WHERE` clause. It'll look a little something like this:

```
knex
  .select("posts.*", "users.full_name")
  .sum("voted.vote")
  .from("users")
  .join("posts", "posts.user_id", "users.id")
  .leftOuterJoin("voted", "posts.id", "voted.post_id")
  .where("posts.group_id", groupId)
  .groupBy("posts.id")
  .groupBy("voted.post_id")
  .groupBy("users.full_name")
```

This produces the SQL output:

```
'select "posts".*, "users"."full_name", sum("votes"."vote") from "users" ' +
    'inner join "posts" on "posts"."user_id" = "users"."id" left outer ' +
    'join "voted" on "posts"."id" = "voted"."post_id" where ' +
    '"posts"."group_id" = ? group by "posts"."id", "voted"."post_id", ' +
    '"users"."name"'
```

You may also find that some of your `GROUP BY`s are unnecessary, but see how you get on.